# Select/dropdown with customized option labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Just want to ask here, although from all the searches that i did, the only answer i ever found was customizing select's option is just not possible.

However i stumbled upon a page with customized option on it

[image]

I was thinking the code of the above might look something like this

```
<select>
    <option>
        <span style="float:left;">Option 1</span>
        <span style="float:right;">Test</span>
    </option>
</select>
```

But as i mentioned, customizing such option is not possible at all.

So i just want to know how to achieve such thing? Is there such javascript/jquery select/dropdown plugins out there that can provide such option look?

Comment: Yes. The most populate is [Select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: Have you tried `inspecting` the page in the image? I think it's a  custom implementation, styled to look like a dropdown

Comment: @adiga yes seems like that select in the image is using dojo's select. It's a custom implementation from inspection (using div instead of select). Just wondering is there any plugin that do similar implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **bootstrap selectpicker plugin**. Which allows you to achieve this.

In bootstrap selectpicker there is an option to add subtext like as below.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-size="5">
  <option data-subtext="Heinz">Ketchup</option>
</select>
```

You can also add button like add new as an option in selectpicker as `<option data-content="<span class='btn btn-link'><i class='fa fa-plus text-primary'></i> Add new</span>"></option>`

Example:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-size="5">
  <option data-subtext="Heinz">Ketchup</option>
  <option data-content="<span class='btn btn-link'><i class='fa fa-plus text-primary'></i> Add new</span>"></option>
</select>
```

After including your html code initialise your selectpicker with jquery as below.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  size: 4
});
```

There are lots options with this selectpicker plugin. Please Refer this [link](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for more details.

If you want to display the ***Subtext as First text*** on the dropdown then you can use the below example.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-size="5">
     <option  data-subtext="<span class='leftMen pull-left'>Sub Text</span>">Main Text </option>
     <option data-content="<span class='btn btn-link'><i class='fa fa-plus text-primary'></i> Add new</span>"></option>
</select>
```

The `leftMen` class is defined as below.

```
.leftMen{
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right:5px;
 }
```

**Sample Screen** is here (*note that this is not the output of the code that i have written here. This is just to show the behaviour of selectpicker plugin*): [image]

**Demo:**

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); //Initialize selectpicker

$(".muted.text-muted").addClass("pull-right"); //after the initialization we add pull-right class to the class 'muted text-muted' so that the sub-text will be displayed on right.
```

```css
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a span.text
 {
   display: inline-block;
    width: 100% !important; //This is also necessary to change the default class by adding this line of code to set the width of the option to 100% then only the sub-text will be pulled to right
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 
  <select class="selectpicker" data-size="5">
    <option data-content="<span class='btn btn-link'><i class='fa fa-plus text-primary'></i> Add new</span>"></option>
    <option  data-subtext="Sub Text1">Main Text1 </option>
    <option  data-subtext="Sub Text2">Main Text2 </option>
    <option  data-subtext="Sub Text3">Main Text3 </option>
    <option  data-subtext="Sub Text4">Main Text4 </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Is this is the expected behaviour of dropdown that you want to work?

Comment: Ermm is the 2nd text can only stick to the left side? Is there a way to make the first text left-aligned and 2nd text right-aligned? From what you shown, it's near perfect just that i think would be perfect if can get the 2nd text right-aligned instead. By the way the plugin you mentioned is Bootstrap-Select right?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Just go through that. For your requirement just use the code as `<option data-subtext="<span class='pull-left'>Sub Text</span>">Main Text</option>` for making the subtext as first text on option.

Comment: One demo also included in the answer. Just go through that. Is this is the thing that you are expected?

Comment: Can't you make the text left and right-aligned? As the one shown on my screenshot?

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply. I have edited my answer. Now the demo code demonstrate how you can align two text contents into left and right as you shown on your question.

Comment: Nice! Exactly as i need it. Going to try now.

Answer (score -1):

Please try select2 for this
https://select2.org/

But yes, you can't just customize the select option. Select2 will create a placeholder for you.

Comment: When you recommend a library in an answer, you must demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.